# How to maintain the same profile in Cognito User Pool using both FB and Google Sign-in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I signedup using Facebook login in AWS Cognito. An unique Identity Id got created.
Is there any possibility or workaround - where we can switch the login with Google Sign-In keeping the Identity ID same? So that the same user profile is maintained.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you link users you will have the same id for both users, In cognito both users will exist but they will have the same id. You can link them in presignup lambda

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminLinkProviderForUser.html